# Need help in creating a java(fx) program which replaces a string by user with another set of strings

Tags: java, encoding, javafx-2

I have created this app, to use for sort of like coding and decoding. I have created the first text area in which the user enters text. The program gets the text. So far, so good. 
Now i need to replace each alphabet by another set of alphabets or numbers or both. I tried using:

```
@FXML
String text;
@FXML
TextArea userText;
@FXML
Label codedTextLabel;
@FXML    
private void getTextAction(ActionEvent textEvent) {
String codedText;
    text = userText.getText();
    //The first if
    if (text.contains("a") {
     codedText = codedTextLabel.getText() + "50"; //50 means a, 60 means b and so on
     codedTextLabel.setText(codedText);
    } else {
     System.out.println("Searching for more text...");
    }
    //The second if
    if (text.contains("b") {
     codedText = codedTextLabel.getText() + "50"; //50 means a, 60 means b and so on
     codedTextLabel.setText(codedText);
    } else {
     System.out.println("Searching for more text...");
```

... so on ...
I have created multiple ifs for the same text area, so that each if gets executed, even if the other is executed. But it generates errors and doesn't work. Any idea how to create such an application to do this very thing?

Comment: What text do you have in your label? What output do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: @assylias The error is that if I write repeating letters, like ababab, only 5060 comes as the result. I need it to be 506050605060.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like that:

```
private static final Map<Character, String> mapping = new HashMap <>();
static {
    map.put('a', "50");
    map.put('b', "60");
    //etc.
}
```

then in your method:

```
String text = userText.getText();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(mapping.get(c)); //should add null check here
}

String encodedText = sb.toString();
```

Comment: please explain your code (both parts). What is mapping? Can it be used in the same way as u did above in fx controller? What is a stringbuilder? What does .toCharArray() do?

Comment: `private static final` ... gives illegal start of expression

Comment: @PratikAnand You need to put the first block of code outside of your method. The map is [a table of correspondence between your two character sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) for efficient lookup. [StringBuilder is what it says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html): it builds strings more efficiently than String concatenation. [`String.toCharArray` returns the individual characters in the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) so we can iterate over them.

Comment: Since JavaFx builds on Java, you would benefit from reading [a tutorial on Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) to better understand the basics.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, in the code outside the method, it should be `mapping.put('a', "50")` Can u tell why `'a'` and not `"a"`?

Comment: @PratikAnand It is just easier to use in this case: to loop over the string's characters, you can call `toCharArray()` which returns an array of `char`s. So by storing `char`s in the map too I can look them up directly. With `map.put("a","50")`, the loop would need something like: `mapping.get(Character.toString(c))` adding a conversion at each iteration.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31033/discussion-between-pratik-anand-and-assylias)